# go-swagger: How to use custom validators

Tags: go-swagger

I would like to be able to define custom validators that can be used in the spec in the same way as `strfmt.UUID` and `strfmt.ObjectId` `"github.com/go-openapi/strfmt"`

For example, I could write in the swagger spec something like this

> ```
>   login:
>     type: string
>     format: login
>   password:
>     type: string
>     format: password
> ```

And after generating the code, I would like to call my own login and password validators.

```
func ValidateLogin(s string) error {
    var err error
    if len(s) == 0 {
        err = multierr.Append(err,...
    }
    if len(s) < 8 {
        err = multierr.Append(err,...
    }
    for n, r := range s {
        if !unicode.IsLetter(r) && !unicode.IsNumber(r) || r >= unicode.MaxASCII {
            err = multierr.Append(err,...
        }
    }
    return err
}

func ValidatePassword(pass string) error {
    var err error
    if len(pass) == 0 {
        ...
    }
    if len(pass) < 8 {
        ...
    }

    var (
        upp, low, num, sym bool
    )

    for n, char := range pass {
        switch {
        case unicode.IsUpper(char):
            upp = true
        case unicode.IsLower(char):
            low = true
        case unicode.IsNumber(char):
            num = true
        case unicode.IsPunct(char) || unicode.IsSymbol(char):
            sym = true
        default:
            err = multierr.Append(err, ...
        }
    }
    if !upp {
        err = multierr.Append(err, ...
    }
    if !low {
        err = multierr.Append(err, ...
    }
    if !num {
        err = multierr.Append(err, ...
    }
    if !sym {
        err = multierr.Append(err,...
    }
    return err
}
```

I suppose it's easy to do, but I didn't find a direct recipe in the go-swagger documentation. Maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

Find the generated file where the API struct is defined. For example, the file will be `restapi/operations/foo_api.go` for an API named `foo` using default package locations.

In that file, find the `RegisterFormat` method. You can use it to register a new format or overwrite an existing format. You will have to supply an object that implements [strfmt.Format](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-openapi/strfmt#Format) and a [strfmt.Validator](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-openapi/strfmt#Validator) function.